# Generating URL's in Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, pdf, url, generator

I am working on a side project on Laravel and I am a junior intern. Currently I need to generate an URL and send that to a specific email, where the user can view a pdf for a limited time and only once.

For now I am just working on the unique URL generation and would like some advice for generating them securely, following standards and for a limited time only.

Would love just some resources or advice.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Never knew you can add DRM to a pdf. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Signed Routes in Laravel.

Probably this help

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#signed-urls

Example:

First of all Before using signed URL you need chek that in your App/Http/Kernel  you have next line uncommented

```php
'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
```

after that in web routes you have to add signed middleware

```php
Route::get('pdf/{id}/{user}/{response}', PdfController::class)->name('pdf.generate')->**middleware('signed')**
```

You finally can use your signed url as

```php
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
URL::temporarySignedRoute('pdf.generate', now()->addHour(), [
    'id' => 25,
    'user' => 100,
    'response' => 'yes'
]);
```

which create a signed url like

https://example.com/pdf/25/100/yes?expires=1521543365
&signature=d32f53ced4a781f287b612d21a3b7d3c38ebc5ae53951115bb9af4bc3f88a87a

Where signature hash include all params in route and avoid manipulation, and the best of all in one hour will expire forever.

Throwing an Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\InvalidSignatureException.
when visited after expiring

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.